# PostgresSQL giving blank screen on installation on Windows 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, postgresql

I downloaded ***postgresql-9.2.4-1-windows-x64***.  When I ran the exe it just gave me a blank screen.

I tried "run as admin" but still the same result. I even uninstalled my anti-virus (Security Essentials) but still nothing changed. Can someone help me in installing the database?

[image]

Comment: Damaged installer file? This is the only report like this I've seen and I really doubt it's the installer. I'd (a) download a fresh copy and (b) look at the installer logs; see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation

Comment: I had downloaded and tried 32 bit installer 64 bit 2-3 times from various sources, but all of the exe are showing the same empty window.

Comment: Then follow that link. Get the installer logs. See if you can tell from them what might be going on. Whatever it is, it sounds like it's specific to your system...